# How to copy a folder structure and make symbolic links to files?

Tags: symlink, file-copy, recursive

I have a folder SOURCE that contains several sub-level folders, each with its own files.

I want to copy this folder in a new folder COPY where I need to copy the directory structure but keep the files as symbolic links to the original files in SOURCE and its subfolders.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1240636/905686.

Comment: [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) kinda does this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's the solution on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin:

```
cp -as SOURCE/ COPY
```

Note that SOURCE must be an absolute path and have a trailing slash. If you want to give a relative path, you can use

```
cp -as "$(pwd)/SOURCE/" COPY
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. Just a note.. SOURCE has to be given with full path (COPY can instead be given in relative terms if one wishes)

Comment: How to make it work if the source directory will be constantly updated with new folders and new  files inside them? Will symlinks to them be automatically created in the destination directory in correct folder structure?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger No, such a command as cp just creates the links once (as you can see from the result). To update the destination automatically you would have to monitor the source directory for changes.

Comment: Can this be done to create relative links?

Comment: @richard if `SOURCE`  is a relative path then I think so. Try it and if this doesn't work I suggest you might want to ask a new question. Reference this one by all means.

Comment: If you want the end symlink to turn out to be a relative path, use this: `cp -as "$PWD/src" "path/to/dest" && symlinks -rc "path/to/dest"`

Comment: @roaima saved my day!!

Comment: `cp -as "$(realpath SOURCE)/" COPY` works no matter if SOURCE is relative or absolute

Answer (score 9):

There are at least 2 standard utilities to build a shadow directory tree of an existing tree, so no need to write code here.

First there's `lndir(1)` from the `xutils-dev` package. It uses symlinks to files. From the man page:

```
NAME
   lndir  -  create a shadow directory of symbolic links to another
             directory tree
SYNOPSIS
   lndir [ -silent ] [ -ignorelinks ] [ -withrevinfo ] fromdir [ todir ]
```

A perhaps better alternative is to simply use `cp` with the right options as the accepted answer suggests.  I'll just give some more hopefully useful detail:

```
cp -al /src/dir /dest/dir    # hard-links to leaf-files
cp -as /src/dir /dest/dir    # symlinks to leaf-files
```

If you don't care about preserving all attributes (ownerships/permissions, times) replace the `a` option (equivalent to `-dr --preserve=all`)
with `r` (recursive only):

```
cp -rl /src/dir /dest/dir    # hard-links to leaf-files
cp -rs /src/dir /dest/dir    # symlinks to leaf-files
```

Comment: `lndir` is also available as a shell script here in case it is not installed: https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11/X11-0.46.4/lndir.sh?txt

Answer (score 2):

You can try a couple of find commands like this:

```
mkdir FULL-PATH-TO-COPY
cd SOURCE
find . \( ! -regex '\.' \) -type d -exec mkdir FULL-PATH-TO-COPY/{} \;
find * -type f -exec ln -s `pwd`/{} FULL-PATH-TO-COPY/{} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this POSIX script will do what you need.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
SOURCE="$1" COPY="$2"
cd "$SOURCE"
find . |
    sed 's!^\./!!' |
    while IFS= read -r ITEM
    do
        if test -d "$ITEM"
        then
            mkdir -p "$COPY/$ITEM"
            continue
        fi
        BASE="${FILE%\/*}"
        ( cd "$COPY/$BASE" && ln -s "$SOURCE/$ITEM" )
    done
```

Directories are created in the target COPY tree. Everything else is symlinked back to the absolute path within the SOURCE tree. Ensure that both SOURCE and COPY are specified as absolute paths (starting with `/`).

If you have a large tree to copy and you want a per-directory progress report, you could add `echo "$ITEM" >&2;`  just before the `mkdir` command.

(I looked at POSIX `cp` and `cpio` but neither seems to have an option for linking to the source with symbolic links.)

Comment: The "line 9 test" comment may have related to ksh on AIX wanting a semicolon to close the brace-enclosed list: `{ mkdir -p "$COPY/$ITEM"; continue; }`

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks. I didn't write a `ksh` script... but it looks like that's necessary for `bash` too. Fixing

Answer (score 1):

GNU `shtool` provides such a feature:

```
shtool mkshadow srcdir destdir
```

Moreover, if your point is to make a shallow copy of a source directory into a build tree, you can distribute `shtool` with your source tree as it is a portable shell script (which provides many other facilities you might be interested in).

Answer (score 0):

If there are not empty dirs in SOURCE which need to be copied

```
find /full/path/to/SOURCE -type f -exec cp -t COPY --parents -s {} +
mv COPY/full/path/to/SOURCE COPY
rm -r COPY/full
```

Comment: Since you're assuming GNU `cp` anyway, why not `cp -as`?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by breaking out the perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $src_dir = "/full_path/to/dir";
my $tgt_dir = "/path/to/new/location";

sub link_or_mkdir {

    #current file is directory
    if (-d) {
        #extract the path
        my $newpath = $File::Find::dir;
        #change the path so 'old' and 'new' are swapped
        $newpath =~ s,^$src_dir,$tgt_dir,g;
        #print the command to make a new dir (doesn't actually do it)
        print "mkdir -p $newpath\n";
    }
    if (-f) {
        my $new_file = $File::Find::name;
        #change the path so 'old' and 'new' are swapped
        $new_file =~ s,^$src_dir,$tgt_dir,g;
        #print the symlink command
        print "ln -s $File::Find::name $new_file\n";
    }
}

find( \&link_or_mkdir, $tgt_dir );
```

`File::Find` is a useful module that allows you to run a specific subroutine on any file within a directory tree. In this case, the sub checks if it's a directory - and if it is, does a `mkdir` or a file - in which case it does a symlink.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for something like the tool `rsnapshot`; it creates copies of arbitrary directories and uses hardlinks where possible. (Have a look at the man page to see whether that fits.)

Comment: No, the question explicitely asks for symlinks and rsnapshot uses hardlinks (as it is a *backup* tool and the files should be kept even if they are removed from the source directory).