# Trying to create same folder structure and symlink files using Cygwin Terminal

Tags: symlink, cygwin

**Followed this post -**
[How to copy a folder structure and make symbolic links to files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196537/how-to-copy-a-folder-structure-and-make-symbolic-links-to-files)

```
cp -al /src/dir /dest/dir    # hard-links to leaf-files

cp -as /src/dir /dest/dir    # symlinks to leaf-files
```

But after working single time on copying my mounted Google drive to a local disk. I seems to have stop working completely. What could be the issue, given I am running the exact same commands

video of it working: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0mitrqaefzcp7faplhv8z/symlink-server-Screen-Recording-2023-10-11-at-6.37.37-PM.mov?rlkey=kbfxp4plnpps3wfxppty7233y&dl=0

Video of it not working:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ryowcu9c0cae2uit232gy/symlink-not-working-Screen-Recording-2023-10-11-at-11.32.41-PM.mov?rlkey=n2e9pzpzqfpw28d0tu19dngbs&dl=0

Comment: I have no idea at all what you're trying to show in those videos. Text in your question would be so much easier for us trying to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not followed [the current highest voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196595/100397) from your referenced [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196537/100397). In particular you've omitted the instructions given in the warning, "that SOURCE must be an absolute path and have a trailing slash."

Your Google drive seems to be mapped in Windows `G:\My Drive` and your destination appears to be something like `E:\Media.01\Content.Media.Server\Series`. You also say you're using Cygwin.

Although Cygwin can mostly cope with Windows drive letters at the beginning of paths, such paths are not absolute in the sense that they start with `/` and you would have almost certainly received warnings from `cp` such as `can make relative symbolic links only in current directory`.

This should work:

```
cp -as '/cygdrive/g/My Drive/' '/cygdrive/e/Media.01/Content.Media.Server/Series'
```